# Importing CSV via API Stopped Working in R

Tags: r

I have some code that I have run multiple times successfully but today it randomly stopped working specifically its coercing a response from an API import into a data frame much like this:

`results <- data.frame(httr::content(response))`

Again this code worked before and other than some filtering of data I have not changed it.

The error I get is:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("xml_document", "xml_node")’ to a data.
```

I trying to fix it and figure out what happened.

I am at a loss here.  Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: The API is now returning an HTML page rather than whatever data it was before. It's likely an error message of some sort. Try looking at `httr::content(response, as="text")` to see what it's returning.

Comment: If MrFlick's comment is correct, I think we may be good here. However, if not, then I think there's very little we can do without knowing the url and/or a representation of the results, etc.

Comment: you might have hit a daily rate limit for querying the API and now it's returning a page error instead of data.

Comment: Howdy folks! Seems like my VPN disconnected randomly and that is what caused the error